# Are there any shorter way for this way?

Tags: python

Lets say i have variables a,b,c,d,e,f.. every time 2 of the 6 variables will have value = 0 randomly. So my code is like this

```
if(a == 0 and b == 0):
   run c,d,e,f
elif(a == 0 and c == 0):
   run b,d,e,f
...
...
continue until end of all combination
```

So the coding will be very long, are there any other approach ?

Comment: what is the meaning of `run b,d,e,f` ?

Comment: Is `run` a function call? You want to run a function with the numbers that aren't zero?

Comment: yes yes something along that way

Answer (score 3):

You can put all numbers into a list and then feed a list comp of that list into the `run` function - ignoring elements that are 0:

```
def run(p1,p2,p3,p4):
    print(p1,p2,p3,p4)

# 3 test cases
for d in [ [ 1,2,0,3,4,0], [0,0,2,3,4,1], [4,3,0,2,1,0]]:
    run(*[x for x in d if x])  #  *[1,2,3] makes python provide the elements as params
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 1
4 3 2 1
```

- `run( *[1,2,3])` is the same as `run(1,2,3)`
- `0` is Falsy - so `*[x for x in d if x]` for a `d=[0,1,2,3,0]` does only use *non falsy values* of `x` in `d`: `*[1,2,3]`

---

- [truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)
- you can exchange the list comp `run(*[x for x in d if x])` against a generator comp if you like `run(*(x for x in d if x))` to avoid the list creation (not that it matters here ;) )

---

@Mehrdad Dowlatabadi raised an interesting side question - if any other of the params is 0 you get an error due to a mismatch between function parameters and provided parameters from the list comprehension - you can negate that by defining defaults:

```
def run(p1=0, p2=0, p3=0, p4=0):
    print(p1,p2,p3,p4)
```

So if you feed `[0,1,2,0,0,0]` into it it will still run.

Comment: @mehrd No - it is not - the other 4 params are not 0 by definition of the question. If you need those, you can use `def run(p1=0,p2=0,p3=0,p4=0)` to substitute any 0 that were given and filtered out by the list comp.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run a function with the variables that aren't set to 0 you can first make a list of elements that are'nt 0

```
elements = [element for element in a, b, c, d, e if element !=0]
```

then call the function with elements list as arguments

```
run(*elements)
```

As a one liner :

```
run(*[element for element in a, b, c, d, e if element !=0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Make run take a list:

```
def run(lst):
    ...
```

then use the filter function:

```
run(filter(None, [a, b, c, d, e, f]))
```

`filter(None, lst)` removes all fals-y elements.